# Writing unit tests for lists in c#

Tags: c#, list

I'm trying to write good unit tests for my project. I want to test my list.

This is the methode I want to test:

```cs
public void RemoveItems(Item item)
{
    Items.Remove(item);
}
```

This is the unit test I wrote:

```cs
Person person = new Person("Jack");
Item item = new Item("Book", person);
person.RemoveItems(item);
Assert.AreEqual(person.Items[0], item);
```

Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance!

This is what I did but when checked with Code Coverage, I saw that it's not covered.

Comment: What exactly is not covered? Also, this test makes no sense, unless you first add items, store the actual item count, remove the item and then test whether the current item count is one less than the stored count. The test `Assert.AreEqual(person.Items[0], item);` will fail if the item was removed successfully. This looks more like a test for adding an item.

Comment: I don't really see a list. Is the `new Item("Book", person)` supposed to add the item to the person? How you've done this here is not what I would call "traditional." I would expect to see something like `person.AddItem("Book")` or some such thing. Then you could check that `person.Items` is empty, or something like that.

Comment: It's true that it looks more like a test for adding an item. the new Item("Book", person) is also supposed to add the item to the person. I had to remove the last line. So i removed Assert.AreEqual(person.Items[0], item); and now is it 100% covered! I think that's all I need now. Thanks guys for your help!